# Mysql Join two Tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables :

```
tbl_jurusan_snmptn
```

column :

```
kode_jurusan varchar(50) 

jurusan varchar(90)
```

and session_ujian_snmptn

Column :

```
   id_ujian
   pilihan_1  varchar(50)
   pilihan_2  varchar(50)
   pilihan_3  varchar(50)
```

in tbl_jurusan_snmptn have values:

```
kode_jurusan    jurusan

10221           Teknik Informatika

10223           Kedokteran

10999           Hukum

11999           Geologi
```

session_ujian_snmptn values :

```
    id_ujian   pilihan_1    pilihan_2    pilihan_3  
      001        10223        11999        10999
      002        11999        10221        10999
```

I've tried query like this :

```
 SELECT * FROM session_ujian_snmptn a 
 INNER JOIN `tbl_jurusan_snmptn` b
 ON a.pilihan_1 = b.kode_jurusan
 OR a.pilihan_2 = b.kode_jurusan
 OR a.pilihan_3 = b.kode_jurusan
 WHERE a.id_ujian = '001'
```

but this show result like this:

```
id_ujian   pilihan_1    pilihan_2    pilihan_3   kode_jurusan    jurusan

   001        10223        11999        10999      10221           Kedokteran
   001        10223        11999        10999      11999           Geologi
   001        10223        11999        10999      1099            Hukum
```

Actually i need it to be like this :

```
  id_ujian   pilihan_1    pilihan_2    pilihan_3   
  001        Kedokteran    Geologi      Hukum
```

Every help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that :

```
   SELECT id_ujian ,
   max(case when a.pilihan_1 = b.kode_jurusan THEN jurusan end )as 'pilihan_1' , 
   max(case when a.pilihan_2 = b.kode_jurusan THEN jurusan end )as 'pilihan_2 ' ,
   max(case when a.pilihan_3 = b.kode_jurusan THEN jurusan end )as 'pilihan_3'      
   FROM  session_ujian_snmptn a 
   inner join `tbl_jurusan_snmptn` b 
   on a.pilihan_1 = b.kode_jurusan 
   or a.pilihan_2 = b.kode_jurusan 
   or a.pilihan_3 = b.kode_jurusan 
   where a.id_ujian = '001'
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37cd4/4)

if you want select all rows then just consider to use GROUP BY

```
 SELECT id_ujian ,
 max(case when a.pilihan_1 = b.kode_jurusan THEN jurusan end )as 'pilihan_1' , 
 max(case when a.pilihan_2 = b.kode_jurusan THEN jurusan end )as 'pilihan_2 ' ,
 max(case when a.pilihan_3 = b.kode_jurusan THEN jurusan end )as 'pilihan_3'      
 FROM  session_ujian_snmptn a 
 inner join `tbl_jurusan_snmptn` b 
 on a.pilihan_1 = b.kode_jurusan 
 or a.pilihan_2 = b.kode_jurusan 
 or a.pilihan_3 = b.kode_jurusan 
 group by id_ujian
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37cd4/16)

Comment: I just surpised for the downvoter if he really see something wrong , or he should let a comment.

Comment: this is a needlessly convoluted way to do it, and breaks as soon as you want to select more than one session_ujian_snmptn row.

Comment: @user1584072 it works also when many rows , check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

you should do multiple JOINS, like this:

```
SELECT a.id_ujian, b1.jurusan, b2.jurusan, b3.jurusan
FROM session_ujian_snmptn a
JOIN tbl_jurusan_snmptn b1 ON a.pilihan_1 = b1.kode_jurusan
JOIN tbl_jurusan_snmptn b2 ON a.pilihan_2 = b2.kode_jurusan
JOIN tbl_jurusan_snmptn b3 ON a.pilihan_3 = b3.kode_jurusan
```

if you need to obtain a result just for id_ujian=001, add the following line:

```
WHERE a.id_ujian = 001
```

Comment: you probably want `b1.jurusan as pilihan_1, b2.jurusan as pilihan_2, ...` to exactly match the requested output

Comment: @ysth even if he do that it will not give expected result.

Comment: @echo_Me that's sqlfiddle screwing up what it shows; in fact the query returns four columns, including all three jurusan values.  but that is why I suggested as pilihan_1, etc.

Comment: @marcosh: you should probably put the where clause on to avoid confusing some people